# How can i insert html in the header of a resourceTimeGridDay/resourceTimeGridWeek in FullCalendar?

Tags: javascript, html, angular, fullcalendar, fullcalendar-5

This is a demo of resourceTimeGridWeek provided by FullCalender
[https://fullcalendar.io/docs/datesAboveResources-demo](https://www.stackoverflow.com/)

I'm trying to add a custom button next to the "Room A" and "Room B" text inside the header cell of each day.
Clicking the button will log to the console the date and the resource id where the clicked button belongs.

I tried using dayHeaderContent but, It only changes the upper header containing the date.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: have you tried any of the [resource render hooks](https://fullcalendar.io/docs/resource-render-hooks)?

Comment: @ADyson I managed to select the html element through resourceLabelDidMount and append some html to it. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1):

As suggested by ADyson here is my solution and a link to a Codepen example.

```
resourceLabelDidMount: function (info) {
      var commentButton = document.createElement("button");
      commentButton.innerText="Click me";
      commentButton.onclick = function () {
        console.log(info.date);
        console.log(info.resource._resource.id)
      };
      info.el.appendChild(commentButton);
}
```

[Codepen](https://codepen.io/moutiayed/pen/QWVMyLB)